# In function 'main': error: invalid operands to binary % (have 'float' and 'int')

Tags: c

This is a simple program which adds digits of a given number

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
void main()
{
    float sum = 0, num;
    printf("Enter any number\n");
    scanf("%f", num);
    while(num!=0)
    {
        sum = sum + (num%10);
        num = num/10;
    }
    printf("Addition of digits of %d is %d", num, sum);
    getch();
}
```

It throws me this error

In function 'main': error: invalid operands to binary % (have 'float' and 'int')
idk why I tried to understand but there's no error and it doesn't print string which I have entered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting `C11`, chapter 6.5.5

> *The operands of the `%` operator shall have integer type.*

`num` is a floating point variable. You may need to use  [`fmod()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fmod) instead.

That said,

```
 scanf("%f", num);
```

is wrong, you need to supply an address to a `float`, not a `float` variable itself. At least you'd need

```
 scanf("%f", &num);
```

keeping aside the success and sanity check.

Comment: I forgot to put ampersand while writing my code here thx its working fine now